# ITunes is locked

Tags: itunes, macbook-pro, ipod

I have installed iTunes on my Macbook-pro successfully today. But the display shows that iTunes is installed but locked and cannot be used for writing. How to unlock and use the iTunes software for recording iTunes
 music on iPod

Comment: You installed iTunes on you Mac or Laptop? Cause iTunes comes preinstalled on Macbooks.

Answer (score 2):

It's not saying that iTunes is locked—rather that the iTunes library is preventing writing to it through permissions or ACLs. Check that you have write permission to your iTunes library.